# Unable to use multiple -replace statements with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, regex

I've been trying to achieve a more consistent file naming scheme and chose PowerShell to help with the task. However, for some reason I can't get the script to replace multiple patterns with underscores.

```
$regex = [regex] '^\d{4}\d{2}\d{2}_'
# $special = [regex] '\. - '

# prepend with date
get-childitem -attributes !directory+!system | where-object {
    !($_.name -match $regex)
} | rename-item -newname {
    (get-date $_.creationtime -format "yyyyMMdd_") + $_.basename + $_.extension
}

# make all letters lowercase
get-childitem -attributes !directory+!system | %{
    $newFilename = ($_.basename.tolower())+($_.extension.tolower());
    move-item $_ $newFilename
}

# replace special chars w underscores
get-childitem -attributes !directory+!system | where-object {
    $_.basename.contains(" ") -or $_.basename.contains("-") -or $_.basename.contains(" ") -or $_.basename.contains(".")
} | rename-item -newname {
    $_.basename -replace "\s+-\s+", "_" -replace "-+", "_" -replace "\.+", "_" -replace "\s+", "_" + $_.extension
}
```

The first two blocks work fine, but the `-replace` statements get ignored, and nothing gets replaced with underscores. I've searched around here and on Google, but I couldn't find a fix that works.

I've also tried with this variation:

```
$_.basename.replace(".", "_") + $_.extension;
$_.basename.replace(" ", "_") + $_.extension
...
```

instead of regex, but that messes up file extensions when it gets to the "." part. It also only works on the first pattern ignoring the rest.

Comment: You just need a pair of well-placed parentheses. See my answer below.

Comment: Why are you testing for **" "** twice? Also, the series of `$_basename.contains...` can be replaced with `Where-Object{  $_.basename -match ' |-|\.' }`

Comment: I'm testing twice because I need to pay more attention. And yes, one of the other answers has already suggested the regex replacement. Good point.

Comment: We haven't heard from you.. Did any of the given answers solve your problem? If so, please consider [accepting](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) it by clicking ✓ on the left. This will help others with a similar question finding it more easily.

Comment: Sorry for that. I was actually contemplating whether to accept your answer or Keith's since you were both so helpful (and had somewhat similar solutions) and then I ended up forgetting to vote altogether :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the third block, you could do

```
# replace special chars w underscores
Get-ChildItem -Attributes !directory+!system | Where-Object { $_.BaseName -match '[-+._\s]' } | ForEach-Object {
    $newName = '{0}{1}' -f ($_.BaseName -replace '[-+._\s]+', '_') , $_.Extension
    $_ | Rename-Item -NewName $newName -Force -WhatIf
}
```

Remove the `-WhatIf` switch if the console output shows the correct new file names.

Example:

```
20190126_this is a file - name that contains + - spaces and dots.pdf
```

Becomes:

```
20190126_this_is_a_file_name_that_contains_spaces_and_dots.pdf
```

Regex details:

> ```
> [-+._\s]    Match a single character present in the list below
>             One of the characters “-+._”
>             A whitespace character (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
>    +        Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
> ```

---

**Edit**

While the above only shows the use of the regex `-replace` operator, the code could be simplified by combining your original three loops into just one:

```
Get-ChildItem -Attributes !directory+!system | ForEach-Object {
    # get the file's BaseName and if needed prefix the CreationTime to it
    $baseName = if ($_.BaseName -notmatch '^\d{8}_') { 
        '{0:yyyyMMdd}_{1}' -f $_.CreationTime, $_.BaseName
    }
    else {
        $_.BaseName
    }
    # do a regex -replace on the base name and combine it with the file's extension
    $newName = '{0}{1}' -f ($baseName -replace '[-+._\s]+', '_') , $_.Extension
    # do the rename using the lowercase $newName
    $_ | Rename-Item -NewName $newName.ToLower() -Force -WhatIf
}
```

---

**Edit 2**

Inspired by [Keith Miller](https://superuser.com/users/881098/keith-miller)'s comment, using a scriptblock for the `-NewName` parameter, you can dispose of the `ForEach-Object` in the code above:

```
Get-ChildItem -Attributes !directory+!system | Rename-Item -NewName {
        # get the file's BaseName and if needed prefix the CreationTime to it
        $baseName = if ($_.BaseName -notmatch '^\d{8}_') { 
            '{0:yyyyMMdd}_{1}' -f $_.CreationTime, $_.BaseName
        }
        else {
            $_.BaseName
        }
        # do a regex -replace on the base name and combine it with the file's extension
        $newName = '{0}{1}' -f ($baseName -replace '[-+._\s]+', '_') , $_.Extension
        # output the new name in lower case
        $newName.ToLower()
    }
```

Comment: ah so I can get by with a single regex, nice! didn't think about that. side question: why does it still work if I get rid of the ForEach-Obect part? i.e., `Get-ChildItem -Attributes !directory+!system | Where-Object {
 $_.BaseName -match '[-+._\s]'
} | Rename-Item -NewName {
 '{0}{1}' -f ($_.BaseName -replace '[-+._\s]+', '_') , $_.Extension
}`

Comment: Because the NewName parameter is a ScriptBlock. From the Help: [The value of NewName is a script block that runs before the value is submitted to the NewName parameter.

In the script block, the $_ automatic variable represents each file object as it comes to the command through the pipeline.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-7)

Comment: Does this make the `ForEach-Obect` part redundant then, or is it still good practice to include it? Does Theo's version have a nested loop with the inner loop always looping once?

Comment: Not the way his code is written, because he's using a string rather than a scriptblock for the  **NewName** parameter. For large data sets, avoiding **ForEach** and using a scriptblock for NewName should be faster. Interesting info [here](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/speeding-up-the-powershell-pipeline). You could probably put all your renaming logic in a defined scriptblock variable and then use something like `gci -file -recurse | ren -NewName $MyScriptBlock`

Answer (score 2):

You could pipe [get-childitem](https://ss64.com/ps/get-childitem.html) over to a [foreach-object](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html) loop to get each file object and its property values. Stack some replace operators with a regex multi-match character expression, and use that to strip out and replace the unnecessary characters within the base file name part.

Essentially this will replace the dots, hyphens, and one or more white space with underscores, and then the stacked replace on top of that will replace two or more hyphens with just one hyphen.

```
$regex = [regex] '^\d{8}_';
Get-ChildItem -attributes !directory+!system | ?{!($_.name -match $regex)} | %{ 
    Rename-Item -path $_.FullName -newname ((get-date $_.creationtime -format "yyyyMMdd_") + $_.basename + $_.extension).ToLower()
    };

Get-ChildItem -attributes !directory+!system | %{
    If(($_.basename + $_.extension) -cmatch "[A-Z]"){Move-Item $_ ($_.basename + $_.extension).ToLower()}
    };

Get-ChildItem -attributes !directory+!system | %{
    Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName "$(Split-Path $_.FullName)\$(($_.Basename -Replace "[.]|-|\s`+","_") -Replace "_{2,}", "_")$($_.extension)"
    };
```

### Supporting Resources

- [Replace](https://ss64.com/ps/replace.html)
- [Get-ChildItem](https://ss64.com/ps/get-childitem.html)
- [ForEach-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)

  > Standard [Aliases](https://ss64.com/ps/get-alias.html) for Foreach-Object: the '`%`' symbol, ForEach
- [Rename-Item](https://ss64.com/ps/rename-item.html)

Comment: Can I do this with -replace or some other way that uses regex? I want to be able to replace multiple spaces, dashes, fullstops and " - " (with 1 or more spaces but a single dash) with a *single* underscore. I was never intending to replace the plus sign, but I guess that's a good idea too.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Simplified COde ---

```
$DateFilter = '^\d{8}_'
$CharFilter = '[\.\s-]+' # 'dot'or one or more whitespace or '-'

$Standarize_Name = {
$Prefix = ''
If ($_.name -notmatch $DateFilter) {
   $Prefix = (get-date $_.creationtime -format "yyyyMMdd_")
}
'{0}{1}{2}' -f $Prefix,
              ($_.BaseName.ToLower() -replace $CharFilter, '_'),
               $_.Extension
}
Get-ChildItem -Attributes !directory+!system |
   Rename-Item -NewName $Standarize_Name
```

Everything is fine in your original code except you need a pair of parentheses. I took your **Rename** ScriptBlock and tested in a simple **ForEach**:

```
PS C:\...\keith>gi 'a b - c.d.txt' | %{$_.basename -replace "\s+-\s+", "_" -replace "-+", "_" -replace "\.+", "_" -replace "\s+", "_" + $_.extension}
The -ireplace operator allows only two elements to follow it, not 3.
At line:1 char:99
+ ... \s+-\s+", "_" -replace "-+", "_" -replace "\.+", "_" -replace "\s+",  ...
+                                                          ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Object[]:Object[]) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadReplaceArgument
```

It errored on the last **-replace** becasue it's reading `+ $_.extension` as a "3rd element".

So the fix is to enclose the **-replace** chain in parentheses and then concatenate with **$_.extension**:

```
# replace special chars w underscores
get-childitem -attributes !directory+!system | where-object {
    $_.basename -match '\s|-|\.')
} | rename-item -newname {
    ($_.basename -replace "\s+-\s+", "_" -replace "-+", "_" -replace "\.+", "_" -replace "\s+", "_") + $_.extension
}
```